# Grep out tags from git repo

Tags: linux, shell, awk, sed, grep

Trying to sed out the different tags from my repo with shell:

```
git ls-remote --tags git@mit.usa.com:s1836/pro-ti.git | awk '{print $2}'
```

Returns, How can I grep out only the different tags as v1, v2, v3, v4:

```
refs/tags/v1
refs/tags/v1^{}
refs/tags/v2
refs/tags/v2^{}
refs/tags/v3
refs/tags/v3^{}
refs/tags/v4
refs/tags/v4^{}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about good old `grep` and `uniq` :

```
... | grep -o 'v[0-9]\+' | sort | uniq
```

Comment: Does it work If my tag is number is v23 also ? or is it only between 0 and 9?

Comment: How would it be if my tag are v1, v.1.1, v1.2, v2, v2.1 etc?

Comment: You are amazing. What does that . do ?

Comment: `[0-9.]` is a *character class*. It stands for all digits from `0` til `9` and the literal dot `.`

Comment: It's actually a `bracket expression` and the `0-9` is a `range expression`. A character class (as also used inside a bracket expression) would be, e.g. `[:digit:]`. `0-9` can contain the digits 0 through 9 but it could contain other chars too depending on the locale (e.g. `[a-z]` is sometimes `[abc...z]` and other times `[aAbBcC...z]`). `[:digit:]` is guaranteed to contain the set of all digits for the current locate. I personally don't know of any locales where `0-9` is going to produce unexpected results though.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I thought the terms where the same as for PCRE.. The PCRE manual states `An opening square bracket introduces a character class, terminated by a closing square bracket`.... [link](http://php.net/manual/de/regexp.reference.character-classes.php)  (You may blame me for using the PHP docs for PCRE, I just feel home there)...

Answer (score 2):

You can pipe above `git` command to this awk:

```
git ls-remote --tags git@mit.usa.com:s1836/pro-ti.git | awk '
    {split($2,a,"[/^{]"); s[a[3]]} END{for (i in s) print i}'
v1
v2
v3
v4
```

Comment: How would you remove the duplicate values?

Comment: Use one `awk` - `git ls-remote --tags git@mit.usa.com:s1836/pro-ti.git | awk '{split($2,a,"[/^{]");print a[3]}'`

Comment: Thanks @Jotne: I have added code to print only unique versions.

Comment: Btw, it is not working for me - meaning no output. This happens because you didn't specified a field delimiter.

Comment: Field delimiter is not needed in this command because we're using default awk delimiter.

Comment: I don't post answer without trying first. I cannot test git command but assuming OP's output in question I have tested awk command. Output shown in my answer is exactly what I get from awk.

Comment: Ok, I was just asking.. I'm wondering why the command does not work in my test (I used the input as shown in the question -hardcoded - , didn't piped the output of git)

Comment: Found it: In the working demo you are using `$1` but here you are using `$2`  ;)

Comment: I used `$2` in answer because that is what OP had in the question :)

Comment: Still the output is not the same as in the working demo (check the sorting order). And this is why I originally commented. Firstly I also prepared a command like yours but I really wonder why the sorting order gets messed up!

Comment: Because there is **no sorting** in this awk command. awk associative arrays are not sorted that's why order will vary system to system. I believe OP just wanted unique values not in sorted order.

Comment: `awk associative arrays are not sorted that's why order will vary system to system`. That's what I didn't expected. Thank you for that information. Will read the manual about assoc arrays again...

Comment: @hek2mgl If you want sorted behaviour then you'll have to use [`PROCINFO`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Controlling-Scanning.html) but that would make it `GNU` awk specific.

Answer (score 1):

With GNU awk for multi-char RS:

```
$ gawk -v RS='(\\^\\{\\})?\n' -F'/' '!seen[$NF]++{print $NF}' file
v1
v2
v3
v4
```

Comment: Then you'd have to figure out which field number you care about since it'd no longer always be $NF. idk if it'll always be $3. I also don't know if `^` can appear elsewhere in the input.

Comment: Good point! +1 for that and the `!seen[$NF]++ ...` part. Nice! :)